# Yii2: sort a relational count column in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

[EDITED 2]

I'm having hard time to sort by the 'topicCount' which is defined as a relational getter on a model 'Tag'.
A Topic can have a lots of Tag, and wish to sort the Tags by how many Topics containing that Tag.

In my models/Tag.php:

```
public function getTopicCount()
{
    return TopicTag::find()->where(['tag_id' => $this->id])->count();
}
```

And in my views/tag/index.php:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        [
             'attribute'=>'topicCount',
             'value' => 'topicCount',
        ],
        'created_at',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template' => '{view}',],
    ],
]); ?>
```

And in my controllers/TagController.php:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Tag::find(),
        'sort'=> [
            'defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_DESC],
            'attributes' => ['id','topicCount'],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

And in my models/TagSearch.php:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tags".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 */
class TagSearch extends Tag
{

public $topicCount;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['topicCount'], 'safe']
    ];
}

public function search($params)
{
    // create ActiveQuery
    $query = Tag::find();
    $query->joinWith(['topicCount']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['topicCount'] = [
        'asc' => ['topicCount' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['topicCount' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        //... other searched attributes here
    ])
    ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'topicCount', $this->topicCount]);

    return $dataProvider;
}


}
```

And in the index view I can see the correct topicCount:

[image]

but on clicking the topicCount column I get the error:

`exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "topicCount" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "tags" ORDER BY "topicCount" LIMIT 100`

Thanks for any guidance..!

---

## [EDIT]

Following Lucas' advice, I've set my dataProvider query in my $dataProvider like this:

```
'query' => $query->select(['tags.*','(select count(topic_tags.id) from topic_tags where topic_tags.tag_id=tags.id) topicCount'])->groupBy('tags.id'),
```

and I got error:

`exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"`

so I reformulated like this:

```
        'query' => $query->from('tags')->leftJoin('topic_tags','topic_tags.tag_id = tags.id')->select(['tags.*','(select count(topic_tags.id) from topic_tags where topic_tags.tag_id=tags.id) topicCount'])->groupBy('tags.id'),
```

and now I get the result:

[image]

apparently the topicCount column is not set, so when I try to sort by it, it returns the error:

`exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "topicCount" does not exist`

but when I try the SQL directly on the DB, it works fine:

[image]

so I suppose the problem is in the way Yii handles the alias 'topicCount'?

---

## 2nd EDIT

Still the same result without the topicCount set in the Grid view.
I show my TagSearch model, TagController and views/tag/index view file below:

**TagSearch**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Tag;

/**
 * TagSearch represents the model behind the search form about `common\models\Tag`.
 */
class TagSearch extends Tag
{

    public $topicCount;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'topicCount'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'topicCount'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Tag::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query->from("tags")->select(["tags.*","(select count(topic_tags.id) from topic_tags where topic_tags.tag_id=tags.id) topicCount"])->groupBy("tags.id"),
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'topicCount' => $this->topicCount,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**Tag model**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tags".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $topicCount
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 */
class Tag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public $topicCount;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['topicCount'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'topicCount' => 'TC',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

}
```

**TagController**

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new TagSearch();
    $myModels = $searchModel->search([]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $myModels,
    ]);
}
```

**tags/index**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'topicCount',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template' => '{view}',],
    ],
]); ?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have topicCount column in Tags table? what is topicCount ??

Comment: hi mohit thanks! no topicCount is not a column in Tag table, I want to get it through relation as in: public function getTopicCount()
{
    return TopicTag::find()->where(['tag_id' => $this->id])->count();
}

Comment: I solved this by adding the column to the select list. In my case, the getter function was missing from the model which I hadn't considered. I thought Yii would look at the results from the query and use those fields as columns. If you have the getter function in the model and the calculation in SQL as a named field, then it seems to work. It's a bit redundant though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So resolved following [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/679/filter-sort-by-summary-data-in-gridview-yii-2-0/):

Since in my case I don't use SUM('amount'), I changed to the following and works perfectly:

Tag model:

```
public function getTopicCount() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(TopicTag::className(), ["tag_id" => "id"])->count();

}
```

TagSearch model:

```
    $query = Tag::find();
    $subQuery = TopicTag::find()->select('tag_id, COUNT(tag_id) as topic_count')->groupBy('tag_id');        
    $query->leftJoin(["topicSum" => $subQuery], '"topicSum".tag_id = id');
```

Just encountered a problem with the generated SQL:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "topicsum"
```

This might be a Postgres-specific issue, had to arrange the code so that the generated SQL becomes like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tags" 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "tag_id", COUNT(*) as topic_count FROM "topic_tags" GROUP BY "tag_id") "topicSum" 
ON "topicSum".tag_id = id
```

note the double-quotation in `"topicSum".tag_id` part.

Hope this might be of help for someone using Postgres on Yii2.

Answer (score 3):

You should alter your query to group and select the count instead of working with relations.

```
$query->groupBy('tags.id')->select(['tags.*','(select count(topic_tag.id) from topic_tag where topic_tag.tag.id=tags.id) topicCount']);
```

This will add `topicCount` as a result object in your query, which will make it behave like an ordinary column.

Also as a side note, for a method to act a relation in Yii2, it must return an `ActiveQuery` object.  Your `getTopicCount()` is returning the count as an int, instead of the query, therefore Yii2 will not treat it like a relation.

Comment: thank you Lucas, I tried you suggestion and got stuck again. Could you please take a look at my edit? Thanks!

Comment: You should not have to add a from() or join() as we are using a subquery, and not a join.  Also I forget to mention that you would need to add a field "public $topicCount;" to your model class Tag so that there is somewhere for the value to be stored.  Please try putting the groupBy() and select() additionals I gave you to the bottom of search()

Comment: thanks for getting back. I've tried your suggestion, but still no luck.  About the from() additional, maybe because I'm using Postgres, it returns an error if I don't put it in $query.  I've edited again my question with a simplified file set. I appreciate if you can show me the light to the exit...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/679/filter-sort-by-summary-data-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) and @arogachev's answer. I put `select` property to get tags count

```
public function search($params)
{ 
$query = SomeModels::find()
         ->select('subQueryName.field_count, someModels.*');
// ....
```

so it will give SQL like this `SELECT subQuery.field_count, someModels.*` ...

at view (grid),

```
[
  'attribute'=> 'field_count',
],
```

Thank you @arogachev , you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

light solution is just reate `view` in PostgreSQL

and generate model via `gii` generator using as model and order & find work.

For update & delete use `table` model for search & index use `view` model.

**For example**

for actions `update` & `delete` use `Tag` model

for actions `index` & `view`  use `TagView` model.