# Yii2 GridView SearchModel for count of relation

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a model `item` that has a `hasMany` relation to an `image` model. In the item `GridView` I have a column that shows how many images that `item` has. I would like to be able to sort by this column, and possibly be able to filter with a checkbox to show only `item`s with no `image`s.

I tried adding a check to the search model to query `with` the `images` relation, and I thought I'd add a `andFilterWhere` for where the `image` count was less than the input value. However I'm not sure the best way to have that logic, is there a better *Yii* way to filter by that count?

**Update**
Following information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782754/yii2-sort-a-relational-count-column-in-gridview) I've updated my `item` model to have a method that returns the relationship count.

I've then update my search model like this:

```
class ItemSearch extends Item
{
    public $image_count;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'product_id', 'manufacturer_id', 'scale_id', 'owner_id', 'quantity'], 'integer'],
            [['sku_number', 'description', 'details', 'condition'], 'safe'],
            [['price', 'sale_price', 'image_count'], 'number'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Item::find();
        $subQuery = Image::find()->select('item_id, COUNT(id) as image_count')->groupBy('item_id');
        $query->leftJoin(['imageCount' => $subQuery], 'imageCount.item_id = id');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
                'id',
                'product_id',
                'manufacturer_id',
                'scale_id',
                'owner_id',
                'image_count' => [
                    'asc' => ['imageCount.image_count' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['imageCount.image_count' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Images'
                ]
            ]
        ]); 

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        if (!empty($this->id)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,
            ]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->product_id)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'product_id' => $this->product_id,
            ]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->manufacturer_id)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'manufacturer_id' => $this->manufacturer_id,
            ]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->scale_id)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'scale_id' => $this->scale_id,
            ]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->owner_id)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'owner_id' => $this->owner_id,
            ]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->image_count)) {
            $query->andWhere(['is','imageCount.image_count',new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);
         }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sku_number', $this->sku_number])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details', $this->details])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'condition', $this->condition]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

The issue now is that the above will produce a query something like this:

```
SELECT `item`.* FROM `item` LEFT JOIN (SELECT `item_id`, COUNT(id) as image_count FROM `image` GROUP BY `item_id`) `imageCount` ON imageCount.item_id = id WHERE `imageCount`.`image_count`=0
```

The issue being `items` that have 0 `image`s are no longer shown (and checking the box shows nothing) because the join will find nothing for that id in the `image` table

Comment: you might need to add your search model and /or any other code relevant to your problem. so that if you are making any mistake, it can be pointed out.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I haven't modified the search model beyond what Gii generated yet. I went to add the andFilterWhere and can't figure out what to put in there.

Comment: see  this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782754/yii2-sort-a-relational-count-column-in-gridview

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That is really close, I'll update my question. The issue is now a `MySQL` one

Comment: see the **Update** part in my answer. it should work at all cost now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you need to count the amount of data in an associated table and sort and filter based on the statistics.

Then your `ItemSearch::search()` method should be able to change to this:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Item::find()->select('*, (select count(*) from image where image.item_id = item.id) as image_count'); // If the table name of your Image table is image, if the table name of your Item table is item

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'product_id',
            'manufacturer_id',
            'scale_id',
            'owner_id',
            'image_count'
        ]
    ]); 

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    if (!empty($this->id)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);
    }
    if (!empty($this->product_id)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'product_id' => $this->product_id,
        ]);
    }
    if (!empty($this->manufacturer_id)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'manufacturer_id' => $this->manufacturer_id,
        ]);
    }
    if (!empty($this->scale_id)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'scale_id' => $this->scale_id,
        ]);
    }
    if (!empty($this->owner_id)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'owner_id' => $this->owner_id,
        ]);
    }
    if (!empty($this->image_count)) {
        $query->andWhere([
            'image_count' => $this->image_count,
        ]);
     }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sku_number', $this->sku_number])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details', $this->details])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'condition', $this->condition]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

However, if your image_count often needs calculations and statistics, and your data volume is large, then it is recommended that you redefine this field into the item table.

**UPDATE:**

My fault, the aggregated fields cannot be filtered by the where condition, but you can use having:

```
$query->andFilterHaving([
    'image_count' => $this->image_count,
]);
```

Comment: That works for displaying and sorting, however when trying to filter by setting image_count to 1 (or anything) I get `1054 Unknown column 'image_count' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `item` WHERE `image_count`='1'`

Comment: @sharf looks at UPDATE

Answer (score 3):

You should check for `WHERE imageCount.image_count IS NULL` rather than `WHERE imageCount.image_count=0` as those rows that don't have any related images would be shown as `null` under the `image_count` and change the condition from

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['imageCount.image_count' => 0]);
```

to

```
$query->andWhere(['is','imageCount.image_count',new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);`
```

Your query should be generated like

```
SELECT `item`.* FROM `item` 
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT `item_id`, COUNT(id) as image_count 
   FROM `image` 
   GROUP BY `item_id`
) `imageCount` 

ON imageCount.item_id = id 

WHERE `imageCount`.`image_count` is NULL
```

---

**Update**

As you were still facing issues so I thought I had some spare time to find this problem and I came up with the following

You were having a problem when filtering for the items having 0 counts for the images I don't have the exact schema that you have but I will state an example below with a similar scenario where I have `Shoots` and their related tags in a junction table `ShootTag` model

- `Shoots`

Below is a sample for schema and data

```
+----+------------+--------+------------+
| id | name       | active | shoot_type |
+----+------------+--------+------------+
|  1 | aslam omer |      1 | modeling   |
|  2 | asif       |      1 | modeling   |
|  3 | saleem     |      1 | modeling   |
|  4 | sajid      |      1 | modeling   |
|  5 | tasleem    |      1 | modeling   |
|  6 | tehseen    |      1 | modeling   |
|  7 | amjad      |      1 | modeling   |
|  8 | shaban     |      1 | modeling   |
|  9 | irfan      |      1 | modeling   |
+----+------------+--------+------------+
```

- `ShootTags`

Below is the sample for schema and data

```
+----------+--------+
| shoot_id | tag_id |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |
|        1 |      2 |
|        1 |      3 |
|        1 |      4 |
|        2 |      1 |
|        2 |      2 |
|        2 |      3 |
|        3 |      1 |
|        4 |      1 |
|        4 |      4 |
+----------+--------+
```

Now considering the above tables and data I have the Search Model with name `ShootsSearch` which I am using to display all the shoots and I want to show the count of the tags against each of the shoot saved inside the `ShootTag` model.

I am not adding the code for GridView as it is not relevant, my search model `ShootsSearch` has the following search method which works correctly for any count against the shoots in the shoottags model.

- What is different from your code is that i am Using the `ShootsSearch` model for the first query rather than the `Shoots` Model as you are using `Item::find();` which should be `ItemSearch::find();` instead as the alias you are using `image_count` is declared in the search model,
- Then the line `new Expression('if(st.totalTags is NOT NULL,st.totalTags,0) as totalTags')` in the main query you need to display the null values as 0 so you can use the conditional select here.
- Then you need to check for the `if ($this->totalTags == '0') {` to apply `$query->andWhere(['IS', 'totalTags', new Expression('null')]);` as the actual value would be `null` for `totalTags` where no tags are available against any `Shoot` and in the else part you will use the `query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'totalTags', $this->totalTags]);`

This works correctly in all three scenarios that you want see the images below

Default view first time

[image]

Search for shoots with totalTags count is 4

[image]

Search for shoots with TotalTags count is 0

[image]

You should replace the following in your code

- `public $totalTags` with `public $image_count`.
- `ShootTags` with `Image`.
- `shoot_id` with `item_id`.
- `ShootsSearch` with `ItemSearch`/`self`.

Here is the search model and the code is tested and working.

```
class ShootsSearch extends Shoots
{
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $totalTags;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'active', 'totalTags'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'shoot_type', 'description', 'totalTags'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $subQuery = ShootTag::find()->select(
            [
                new Expression('shoot_id, COUNT(shoot_id) as totalTags')
            ]
        )->groupBy('shoot_id');
        $query = ShootsSearch::find()->alias('s')
            ->select(
                [
                    's.*',
                    new Expression('if(st.totalTags is NOT NULL,st.totalTags,0) as totalTags')
                ]
            )->leftJoin(['st' => $subQuery], 'st.shoot_id=s.id');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(
            [
                'query' => $query
            ]
        );

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'active' => $this->active
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'shoot_type', $this->shoot_type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description]);

        if ($this->totalTags == '0') {
            $query->andWhere(['IS', 'totalTags', new Expression('null')]);
        } else {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'totalTags', $this->totalTags]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem. For starters, when no filter is provided, items without images do not appear at all, and then filtering by null shows no records, as no items without images are in the original query to begin with.

Comment: @sharf i dont see the updated code in your question its the same old code

Comment: I hadn't bothered because it wasn't really relevant. I just did however. The issue is the initial query, not the filter. When no filters are applied, it does not return the correct entries.

Comment: well it can help me troubleshoot and find the fix if possible by replicating at my end @sharf

Comment: since each image can only belong to one item, I don't have a linking table, and instead have the foreign key on the image table. I'll take a look at your example and see what I can come up with. I haven't had a chance to look at it recently. thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @sharf that won't make a difference even if an image belongs to one ite only and my example has multiple assignments and also if you have a foreign key and not a junction table all we need is the count and the foreign key i am confident it will work,

Comment: This is giving me the search functionality, but I can't sort by the count. Which is the opposite of @Luna's answer. I'll mess around with it a bit more to see if I can work out a solution with both, if not I'll just pick one or the other.